# BroadcastReceiver when application is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest which receives notifications from the `AlarmManager`. This all works great while the app is running i.e. the `onReceive()` method is being called.

However, if I force-stop the app so that I can test if the `BroadcastReceiver` will still receive notifications from the `AlarmManager` while not running, the `onReceive()` method is never called.

Can force-stop not be used to test the `AlarmManager` & receiver in this way? There seems to be some responses saying it won't work, and some saying it should.

If not, is there a way of testing this?

Comment: Have you defined your `BroadcastReceiver` on the manifest?

Comment: @jFort : Are you using one of the `WAKEUP` types for the alarm? If not then that might be the cause but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, the broadcast receiver is defined in the manifest. And the alarm manager is defined AlarmManager.RTC

Comment: @jFort : Only `RTC`? Not `RTC_WAKEUP`?

Comment: I think RTC_WAKEUP will wake the device but they're only simple reminders so that's not what I'm intending to do.

Comment: @jFort : But have you tried `RTC_WAKEUP` to see if it fixes the situation? It's worth a try at least for testing purposes. I can tell you that a correctly registered `BroadcastReceier` will, in fact, be called even if the app has been force-closed. My network state monitoring receiver certainly is. Perhaps alarms are just a different case.

Comment: Ckeck it out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35457280/925504)

Answer (score 3):

If your receiver is registered in your manifest, it should always work. Even if your app is force closed.

The problem might be the alarm. The alarms might be getting deleted, once your app force closes.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I know it **should** work I'll keep on troubleshooting. Is there a way I can find out what's happening to these alarms?

Comment: A crash means, something unexpected happens. So, you should probably re-initialize the alarms when you program recovers. I don't exactly know what happens to the alarms. Sorry

Comment: For android > version 3.0, your receiver will stop working when your app is force closed!

Comment: As Hoang says, this answer has not been correct for many years, and many Android versions.

Comment: i am not using Alarm Manager i am using call / phone state broadcast receiver i am getting issue is when app is not running at that time call broadcast not getting

Comment: Did you fin\d any solution? I face same issue @MehulTank

Comment: @BrindaRathod You can add  
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
intent-filter android:priority="999"

Answer (score 1):

As per comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712736/383414), you cannot test this type of thing by killing the app yourself. You must throw an exception so the app dies "naturally".

Answer (score 0):

May this could be your device problem. In Xiomi, Oppo, Vivo, honor, and Letv mobiles user has to give an autostart permission to the application and for this, you should ask the user  to enable this manually you cant done it programmatically