# Activity which registered a broadcast receiver finished? what happens to the receiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

In Android, I have a receiver class `(MyLocalBroadcastReceiver)`, and I have another activity (`MyActivity`) which does, `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Context).registerReceiver(MyLocalBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter)`.

Now in some case, consider that `MyActivity` gets destroyed or it is finished. what happens if the registered receiver is fired? will it still continue to receive the **broadcasted** intent or since the activity died/finished/destroyed `MyLocalBroadcastReceiver` **will be unregistered too**?

Comment: receiver will close too . See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824341/keep-broadcast-receiver-running-after-application-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

Your BroadcastManager will hold the reference to your receiver until you'll call unregisterReceiver and it may cause exception if activity is destroyed and BroadcastManager is trying to Broadcast some intent, you should explicitly call LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(Context).unregisterReceiver(MyLocalBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter) preferably on onPause in your activity.