# How to get time change broadcast even if app closed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

i have an app and it's important for me to detect time changes. so far i have receiver with proper intent filters like this:

```xml
<receiver
  android:name=".MyReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and this is my receiver :

```java
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor spe =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()).edit();
        spe.putLong("UFCount", 1));
        spe.putLong("FCount", 1));
        spe.commit();
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Your job is being done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

this receiver only works when the app is open\in-the-background . how can i make this receiver to work even if the app is closed?

Comment: You can check this link  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/16824692/4049612](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16824692/4049612)

Comment: @Krishna i don't feel good about having a service running all the time . i don't think its a optimal way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Since the application is closed, there is no UI (i.e. no Activity) to display the Toast. At this point, there should be an exception in Logcat. You might also add a logcat trace before displaying the Toast, like `Log.d("MyReceiver", "in onCreate()");` and you should see it even when the app is closed.

Instead of displaying a Toast, you could for instance send a [local notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), which is allowed because it does not require an Activity from your app.

Comment: I did use the Log but it doesn't work. i searched for the Log and it doesn't show up hence the receiver didn't triggered

Comment: If you're looking at logcat from Android Studio, can you try and disable the logcat filters and see what you get? AS has sometimes trouble getting traces from closed applications

Comment: yes i did that too. still nothing shows up. i wonder if `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` action has the flag to open closed app component  ?!