# How to update a Parse push notification instead of creating a new one

Tags: notifications, parse-platform

With my app, the Parse module sends out a notification each time a picture is sent to the Android recipient.  The recipient then know to login to the app and receive the picture.  My problem is that if the same recipient is getting many pictures sent to him, he will get many notifications for the app.  Is there a way to update any existing Parse notification on and Android device to show the waiting count, instead of sending multiple notifications?  I have searched through Parse documentation and here at Stackoverflow but can't find any info on how to do this.

Comment: try something like this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395110/broadcastreceiver-not-working-when-app-is-not-running

Answer (score 0):

yes, I am facing the same problem, The resolution is that , if you dont send title and alert in parse notifications, it will not create the automatic notifications in the device, so you will have to handle them in your broadcast receiver and create your own notifications, you can have a NOTIFICATION_ID for each notification you create and update the count by getNumber and setNumber i think.

here is a link

https://www.parse.com/questions/update-notification-in-android

Update: Sorry for getting back to you late on this but this might help someone else. Even If your app is not running, You will still get the notification. I have tested it on my own BroadcastReceiver which generates Modified notifications with bitmap, and positive, negetive button for response.

Comment: The problem with creating my own notifications is that it requires my app to be running to receive them.  The whole purpose of the way I use the notifications is to show waiting content when the app is not running, for an app that is not used all day every day. The default Parse notifications do this without having the OS shutdown the notifier. I may be able to re-write the default Parse notification code, but I don't know if just substituting my own receiver is enough.  Won't the Android OS shut it down if it detects no activity?

Comment: try something like this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395110/broadcastreceiver-not-working-when-app-is-not-running

Comment: The solution was actually simpler.  I just created a separate application class and initialized Parse there. That way when my app gets shut down, the Parse service still runs, or gets restarted.