# Android broadcast is not working when the app is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Please don`t vote down if this is a silly question please share some light here

i want to created an app for saving call history

for that i followed 
http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/detect-incoming-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android/

this site 
but i`m not getting the event when the app is not running.Please help

i want to get the event when a incoming call is received even when the app is closed

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sars.broadcasttest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".IncommingCall">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

class file

```
package com.sars.broadcasttest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by athulbabu on 18/08/15.
 */
public class IncommingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int i=0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("IncomingCall", "Call catched test"+i++);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Calll Intent Detected. test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach more details not a link to another site

Comment: When the app is running the broadcast is working fine but when it is closed   it is not working

Comment: overrride default back button press method, that when it pressed your android home will be up..

Comment: i don`t want run the app (Activity) it does`t have any activity in final app

Comment: Ckeck it out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35457280/925504)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons you have to run app at least once after install to get the BroadcastReceiver working.

Read this section: Launch controls on stopped applications
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html

Comment: yes i had run the app and force closed from settings then it wont work or after a reboot it won`t work

Comment: After force close, app is in StoppedState and before first run. You can't do anything about that, this is new Google politics after Android 3.1.

Comment: what should i do to run my app after a call received ?